# Having trouble uploading data set on R

Tags: r, dataset, read.table

Here is the link to the data set I'm trying to upload: https://www.kaggle.com/zynicide/wine-reviews?select=winemag-data-130k-v2.csv

I have the data set and the R Notebook saved to the same folder on my desktop.

Here is my code:

```
getwd()
wine = read.table("winemag.data_first150k", sep = ",", header = T, quote = "")
```

This is my error: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Comment: You would need the extension as well `.csv` i.e. `""winemag.data_first150k.csv"`

Comment: Ok i did that and now i have this error:

Comment: [1] "/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/BUSSQOM"
Error in read.table("winemag-data_first150k.csv", sep = ",", header = T, : more columns than column names

Comment: add `fill = TRUE`

Comment: i still got the same error

Comment: Is your file present in your working directory? Try to use complete path. `wine = read.table("Users/hannahbeegle/....../winemag.data_first150k.csv", sep = ",", header = T, quote = "")
`

Answer (score 0):

We need the full file name with the extension

```
wine <- read.table("winemag.data_first150k.csv", sep = ",", 
   header = TRUE, quote = "", fill = TRUE)
```

---

Tried the code after downloading the data

```
wine <- read.csv(file.choose(), fill = TRUE)

dim(wine)
#[1] 150930     11
```

Comment: when I do that I get this error: 

Error in read.table("winemag-data_first150k.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE, : more columns than column names

Comment: @Hannah i downloaded the data and read the data without any issues.  Please check my update